# Solved: How to store future date in firestore with firebase admin in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to add a future date in firestore with firebase-admin via nodejs. I am able to get it to save the current date correctly `current_period_begin`, but cannot figure out how to get it to store the date + 1 month in the future `current_period_end`. It is storing as "December 31, 1969 at 4:00:00 PM UTC-8". I have even gotten it to log correctly (console.log), but it does not store the correct date.

I've tried this numerous ways as well as with moment.js, have looked at other questions similar to this on here to no avail, and am at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
const date = new Date()
const oneMonthFromNow = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
await db.collection('providers').doc(eventObject.metadata.firebase_uid).set({
    payment_received: true,
    current_period_begin: admin.firestore
        .Timestamp.fromDate(date),
    current_period_end: admin.firestore
        .Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(oneMonthFromNow)),
        // moment().add(1, 'months').add(1, 'days'),
}, {merge: true})
```

I have also tried this and it also saves the epoch in Firestore even though the console.log is a month in the future.

```
let date = new Date()
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
            // const oneMonth = new Date(oneMonthFromNow)
            await db.collection('providers').doc(eventObject.metadata.firebase_uid).set({
                payment_received: true,
                current_period_begin: db
                    .Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
                current_period_end: db
                    .Timestamp.fromDate(date),
            }, {merge: true})
```

Solution: It turns out my code was correct all along. I was sending a webhook to my function on my github rather than locally, which explains why the code is correct.

Comment: I think you're wrapping a date in a date in a timestamp. How about `admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(oneMonthFromNow)` (so minus the `new Date()` wrapper)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've tried that and just did again. It's saving `December 31, 1969 at 4:00:00 PM UTC-8` in firestore. Webstorm underlines that and says `Argument type number is not assignable to parameter type Date`

Comment: Ah, got it. The `Date.setMonth` doesn't return a new `Date` object, but manipulates the existing object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth. So `admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date)` should work better. I'm still not entirely sure why it interprets it as the epoch though.

Comment: The `admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date)` works correctly, but `admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(oneMonthFromNow)` saves it as the epoch. It's the `oneMonthFromNow` that I'm stuck on. When I try `new Date(oneMonthFromNow)` on Mozilla's site, I get July 25th, but I still get the epoch in Firestore.

Comment: After you call `date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)`, the `date` object itself is modified. So you can pass that to Firebase, instead of the return value.

Comment: `let date = new Date(); console.log(date);  "Thu Jun 25 2020 16:21:36 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1) 1595719296476
console.log(date);
 "Sat Jul 25 2020 16:21:36 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"` Sorry for it being hard to read.

Comment: I solved it! It was sending a webhook to invoke this function from my github instead of on my local machine. The code was correct all along. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to hear Atlee. I voted to close your question as "not reproducible/a typo" as it's unlikely that someone in the same situation will stumble upon this.